# Wrong messages sequence with socket DataInputStream BufferedInputStream in Android app

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I have a problem with receiving irregular sequence of the byte messages I send from another device.

The setup is the following: I have an Android app (client) and Real-Time system (server) with Ethernet both connected in a LAN through router, which talk with raw bytes communication.

From the Android app I send request, which causes the server to respond with several messages - the first one with 8 bytes, the following messages have 27 bytes. I have debugged the server and I am sure the first message it sends is the 8th-byte one, followed by the others.

About the app - I use the Main Activity to handle transmission of data through the socket, and additional thread to handle reception of data.
The thread makes post through Handler to the Main Activity, when new data has been received. In this post is called a process to parse the received data.

**TbProtocolProcessor** is a class I use to handle my custom protocol. It can create a byte array for me to send as request for specific function, and it has a state-machine to process expected response from the server. **InetHandler** is nested class I use to handle my connectivity only.

My question is - why would my Android app return me the first message having size 8, but contents like the next messages? Interesting effect is that if I send ONLY the 8-byte message, without any others, it is received and passed to my app correctly.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private TbProtocolProcessor tbProtPrcs = null;
private InetHandler inetHandler = new InetHandler(this);
private static Handler msgHandler = new Handler();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tbProtPrcs = new TbProtocolProcessor(this);
}

// Implementation of InetControl interface
public void ConnectToIP(String strIP, int port)
{
    inetHandler.AttachToIP(strIP, port);
}
public void Disconnect()
{
    inetHandler.DetachFromIP();
}

public void GetFilesList()
{
    byte[] data = TbProtocolProcessor.buildFilesGetList();
    inetHandler.SendData(data, data.length);
    TbProtocolProcessor.setExpectedResult(
            TbProtocolProcessor.TB_STATE_WAIT_MUL_FILESLIST,
            data[1],
            1);
}

private class InetHandler
{
    protected static final int cTARGET_PORT_UNASSIGNED = 0xFFFF;
    protected String targetIP = null;
    protected int targetPort = cTARGET_PORT_UNASSIGNED;
    protected boolean isConnected = false;
    protected Socket socket = null;
    protected DataOutputStream sockStrmOut = null;
    protected DataInputStream sockStrmIn = null;
    protected Context context = null;

    public InetHandler(Context ctx) {
        if (ctx != null)
        {
            context = ctx;
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        byte[] indata = new byte[100];
        int inCntr;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(targetIP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, targetPort);
                socket.setKeepAlive(true);
                // DataOutputStream is used to write primitive data types to stream
                sockStrmOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                sockStrmIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

                if (socket.isConnected()) {
                    isConnected = true;
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //findViewById(R.id.action_connect).setBackgroundColor(0xFF60FF60);
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // TODO: 
            while (isConnected) {
                try {
                    inCntr = sockStrmIn.read(indata);
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (inCntr > 0) {
                    msgHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if ( tbProtPrcs.Process(indata, inCntr) ) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Operation Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Operation ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void AttachToIP(String sIP, int iPort)
    {
        if ( (isIPValid(sIP)) && (iPort < cTARGET_PORT_UNASSIGNED) )
        {
            targetIP = sIP;
            targetPort = iPort;
            // Start the connection thread
            new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
        }
    }

    public void DetachFromIP()
    {
        try {
            socket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean SendData(byte[] data, int size)
    {
        boolean bResult = false;

        try
        {
            if ( (data != null) && (size > 0) && (sockStrmOut != null) ) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Sending...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sockStrmOut.write(data, 0, size);
                bResult = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bResult;
    }

    public boolean isIPValid (String ip) {
        try {
            if (ip == null || ip.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }

            String[] parts = ip.split( "\\." );
            if ( parts.length != 4 ) {
                return false;
            }

            for ( String s : parts ) {
                int i = Integer.parseInt( s );
                if ( (i < 0) || (i > 255) ) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that `read()` fills the buffer. It isn't specified to do that. See the Javadoc. If you want to fill the buffer you must use `readFully()`.

NB `isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at the point you're testing it.

Comment: I don't assume the read() fills the buffer - it's the opposite - I assume it is big enough not to be filled, but only to contain my data, which amount should be in inCntr variable. I'm not sure if you understand the problem - I get the size of the first message, which I expect, but the data inside is unexpected.